# Recursive function occasionally returns a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I'm working on implementing a divide-and-conquer algorithm that finds the two points closest to eachother and the distance between them. My final solution finds the correct answer (compared to using brute force), but about 1/3 of the time would return a segmentation fault error. I've been working on fixing this issue for a couple of days now, adding print statements here and there, but couldn't find the issue. I would appreciate it if someone took a look at my code.

Comment: Where does your debugger put the segmentation fault?

Comment: Using the same input data or different data every time? You might be running out of stack space given the function is recursive. Try increasing the stack are re-running on the data that crashes the program.

Comment: @Cedric just tried a debugger and it says the segmentation fault is happening at `for (j=i+1; j<n && (Yprime[j].y-Yprime[i].y) < minSoFar; j++) {`.

@iksemyonov I'm using randomly-generated points as input. I tried holding the input size and seed constant and the segmentation fault still happens pretty randomly.

Comment: Also, increasing the stack size didn't help (I'm testing with N<20 anyways).

Comment: I already had this kind of problem caused by the subscript-operator of the std::vector class. Try the solution I suggested in an answer to this question! Hope this helps!

Comment: There’s a good answer below, but two useful techniques in cases like this are to reproduce your bug in a debugger, and backtrace it, so you see exactly which parameters cause it and how they were generated.

Comment: @Lorehead If you're talking about 1201ProgramAlarm's answer, OP as already commented it, saying it does not work. Anyway, since he is testing this code in a controlled environment, it would have been unlikely that X < Y, since it does work 2/3 of the time. Even though this is an issue, it is not what's causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: To help with debugging, output your random seed so that when it crashes you can then hardcode the seed and have reproducible behaviour that you can step through

Answer (score 2):

Your "divide" loop assumes that `X` and `Y` have the same number of elements.  If `Y` has fewer than `X` you'll run into undefined behavior, which could be funny results or a crash.

Comment: Suggest a solution maybe? just a few lines to be replaced, their commented replacement (why necessary)

Comment: That makes sense. I tried splitting the loop into two: one for `Y` with condition `i<Y.size()` and one for `X` with condition `i<n`, but I'm still getting segmentation faults. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your access method for the vectors. Vector subscript-operator does seem to have an eratic behaviour in some compilers/platforms (at least from my perspective).  <s>I think the problem comes from it being a linked list, resulting in being non-contiguous in memory, but that's just a guess.</s> (EDIT: std::vector are contiguous in memory, the problem is something else) Try using iterators instead (easy-peasy with `auto` keyword), such as:

```
for (auto iter = Yprime.begin(); iter != Yprime.end(); iter++) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Hope this works for your case!

Comment: Just edited my post about that, saw your comment after. Sorry about that. Although, I explicitly said **"but that's just a guess"**. So you're kinda wrong saying I was _completely wrong_. Just try it, on LLVM I get segmentation fault for using subscript operator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It took me a while to reimplement my code this way. I still got the same error nonetheless...

Comment: Sorry to hear that... I had a similar problem once and it did solve it... Otherwise, the only other thing I see is that the statement `abs(Y[i].x - mid.x) < D.dsq` is false at least once, making `Yprime` size less than `n`.